# fail to login to npm 'npm errno: -4048'

Tags: npm, nvm

I'm struggling with this issue for a while.
[image]
currently, I'm using nvm. npm version 5.0.0
I've tried to:

- install npm version lower than 5.3.
- remove node and npm completely and reinstall it
- delete all files that connected to npm and reinstall everything back.
- delete .npmrc file and recreate
- `npm clean cache --force`
- `npm config get registry - https://registry.npmjs.org/`
- running the command from administrator

The login details are correct.
Don't know what else I can do, I will appreciate any advice 
Thanks

Comment: Try these fixes - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17997

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz thanks, already tried this